# $(x+y+z)^3-(y+z-x)^3-(z+x-y)^3-(x+y-z)^3=24xyz$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, problem-solving

The question given is

> Show that $(x+y+z)^3-(y+z-x)^3-(z+x-y)^3-(x+y-z)^3=24xyz$.

What I tried is suppose $a=(y+z-x),\ b=(z+x-y)$ and $c=(x+y-z)$ and then noted that $a+b+c=x+y+z$. So the question statement reduced to $(a+b+c)^3-(a^3+b^3+c^3)$. Then I tried to invoke the identity $(a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc)=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)$ by adding and subtracting $3abc$ in the question statement. After doing all this when I substituted back the values of $a,b$ and $c$, I ended up with the initial question statement.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps try expanding it? You only have to do it once, then the others can be switched according to the powers of the negative term.

Comment: @Alizter Ok, but there might be some trick too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Following your way,

$$(a+b+c)^3-(a^3+b^3+c^3)=3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$

Comment: How is $(a+b+c)^3−(a^3+b^3+c^3)=3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$?

Comment: I couldn't understand your comment. I found a different way. I expanded $((a+b)+c)^3$ and then $(a+b)^3$ in the next step and got the result.

Comment: I didn't get this step, $
(a+b+c)^2+(a+b+c)a+a2=⋯=3(b+c)(c+a)$ Are you rearranging terms here?

Comment: @user103816, $$(a+b+c)^3-a^3=(a+b+c-a)\{(a+b+c)^2+(a+b+c)a+a^2\}$$  $$=(b+c)[3(a^2+ca+ab+bc)-(b^2-bc+c^2)]$$  $$=3(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)-(b^3+c^3)$$  But this is more complex than your method

Answer (score 10):

Put $z = 0$, the LHS vanishes.  So $z$ must be a factor.  By symmetry $xyz$ must be a factor.  As LHS is of third degree, the only other factor must be a constant, try $x=y=z=1$ to get that...

Comment: How can we prove that the degree of LHS can't be higher than 3?

Comment: @user103816: It is obvious. Each term is of degree at most 3

Comment: @user21820 But how can we prove that if we expand the LHS the degree will remain 3?

Comment: @user103816: Don't you know what the basic operations like $+$ and $\times$ do to the degree?

Comment: @user21820 Perhaps addition conserves the degree and since multiplication is repetitive addition so the degree must also be conserved. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @user103816: Try small examples yourself. I feel you're not even putting any effort into it, but here are two examples: $(x^2+y) + (z-x^2)$ and $(x+yz+w) \times (x-yz+w)$. Anyway you don't even need to know the exact degree of the answer, but just an upper bound.

Comment: @user103816: And polynomials have nothing to do with repeated addition.....

Comment: @user103816 Adding or subtracting polynomials of like degree will never result in a polynomial of higher degree.  Write out the form of a general cubic polynomial and check how the addition (or subtraction) would work.

Comment: @user21820 I understand that in addition the degree must remain same but I fail to see why it so with multiplication. Macavity, I know that adding like terms don't change the degree but why is it same with multiplication?

Comment: @user103816 Where are you multiplying?

Comment: @Macavity I mean I fail to see why it is true for any arbitary pair of polynomials. I know that if I multply two specific polynomials then the degree of the product will deg(poly.-1)+deg(poly.-2).

Comment: @user103816 again, where are you multiplying?

Comment: I am multipying in my head.

Comment: @user103816: It is by the definition of multiplication of polynomials. If you write down the definition, you will see immediately the degree of the result.

Comment: Perhaps I get it now. If I apply the distributive law then I can see the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that,

$\begin{align}(x+y+z)^3-(x+y-z)^3&=2z\left((x+y+z)^2+(x+y-z)^2)+(x+y)^2-z^2\right)\\&=2z\left(3(x+y)^2+z^2\right)\tag{1}\end{align}$

and,

$\begin{align}(x-y-z)^3-(x-y+z)^3&=-2z\left((x-y-z)^2+(x-y+z)^2)+(x-y)^2-z^2\right)\\&=2z\left(3(x-y)^2+z^2\right)\tag{2}\end{align}$

Therefore,

$(x+y+z)^3+(x-y-z)^3-(x-y+z)^3-(x+y-z)^3\\=\bigl((x+y+z)^3-(x+y-z)^3\bigr)+\bigl((x-y-z)^3-(x-y+z)^3\bigr)\\=2z\left(3(x+y)^2+z^2\right)-2z\left(3(x-y)^2+z^2\right)\\=2z(3\cdot 4xy)\\=24xy$

Answer (score 1):

Pascal's (or Tartaglia's) Tetrahedron: the left outline is a binomial expansion of $(x+y)^3$, while the right outline is a binomial expansion of $(x+z)^3$ and the bottom outline is a binomial expansion of $(y+z)^3$. Each of them is highlighted in yellow for identification purposes. Furthermore, you may notice that the terms with the highest powers are situated at the vertices, because the coefficients of those terms are “1”. Imagine to rewrite this equation in "graphically", treating expressions in triangles as the components of a matrix (which add-term contracts):
[image]
Hence the claim.

Comment: It is beyond my level.